# How to invoke MessageInspector and ParameterInspector without adding entries in Web.config

Tags: wcf, validation, visual-studio-2012

I am able to invoke parameterInspectors and MessageInpectors in my WCF service by adding the required entries in web.config however is there any way to invoke the inspectors without adding the entries in web.config?

Comment: Yes, if you use a custom ServiceHost.  You can invoke the inspectors that way as well, when the ServiceHost starts.

Comment: Thanks Tim, can you please provide an example, or point to an article for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example.  Assume you have a class called `CustomServiceHost` that derives from `ServiceHost`, and that you have two behaviors - `MyParameterInspector` and `MyMessageInspector`.

In the code for your `CustomServiceHost`, you would override the `ApplyConfiguration` method to add the behaviors (don't forget to call the `base` method as well):

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{

    protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {

        base.ApplyConfiguration();
        this.Description.Add.Behaviors(new MyParameterInspector());
        this.Description.Add.Behaviors(new MyMessageInspector());
    }
}
```

Note that I've only shown the portions of the code that are relevant.

If you're hosting the service in IIS, you'll also need to implement a custom service host factory that creates the instance of your service host.  The `ApplyConfiguration()` method will be called when the host is instantiated.

You can also check the following links from Carlos Figueira MSDN blog, which have some code snippets:

[WCF Extensibility -
   IParameterInspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx)

[WCF Extensibility - Message
   Inspectors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx)